# how to parse complex object using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, stream

i have json object as below, which I need to parse and return comma separated values

```
{
 "globalCode" : "12"
  "fields" : [
     {
           "localCode" : "72879",
           "fieldValues" : [
                {
                      "value" : null,
                      "subFields" : [
                           {
                                 "localCode" : "980"
                                 "subFieldValues" : [
                                         {
                                          "value" :  "lon"
                                         }
                                  ]
                           },
                            {
                                 "localCode" : "98"
                                 "subFieldValues" : [
                                         {
                                          "value" :  "KPO"
                                         }
                                  ]
                           }
                              

                      ]
                }       
           ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to achieve the following using java 8 streams. The following function should return string
"lon,KPO"

line number 2 in below function, returns **one field object** from array of fields
I am not sure how to add else part using java 8 Streams.

```
public String getValue(){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    List<Field> fields  = //get fields for globalCode 72879 // line 2
    for(Field field : fields    ){
         List<FieldValue> fieldValues : field.getFieldValues();
         for(FieldValue fieldValue : fieldValues)
         {
           if(fieldValue.getValue() != null){
               buffer.append(fieldValue.getValue());
               buffer.append(",");
           }
           else{
               List<SubField> subFields = values.getSubFields();
               for(SubField subField: subFields ){
                  List<SubFieldValue> subFieldValues : subField.getSubFieldValues();
                 for(SubFieldValue subFieldValue : subFieldValues  ){
                        buffer.append(subFieldValue.getValue());
                        buffer.append(",");
                 }        
              }
            }
         }
    }
     return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Is your code working? there are statements that do not even compile in java, e.g. `List<SubField> subFields = values.getSubFields();`, there is no `values` object anywhere in your code. Please provide a working code example. And line `List<FieldValue> fieldValues : field.getFieldValues();` is also not compiling, guess you need to replace `:` with `=`.

Comment: "_I want to achieve the following using java 8 streams_" - yet you've not provided any Stream related code. Show us your Stream related code that you cannot get to work and describe your problem through that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
fields.stream().flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream()).forEach(fieldValue -> {
            if (fieldValue.getValue() != null) {
                buffer.append(fieldValue.getValue());
                buffer.append(",");
            } else {
                List<SubField> subFields = fieldValue.getSubFields();
                for (SubField subField : subFields) {
                    List<SubFieldValue> subFieldValues = subField.getSubFieldValues();
                    for (SubFieldValue subFieldValue : subFieldValues) {
                        buffer.append(subFieldValue.getValue());
                        buffer.append(",");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And if you want also to replace the for loops in the `else` statement:

```
fields.stream().flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream()).forEach(fieldValue -> {
            if (fieldValue.getValue() != null) {
                buffer.append(fieldValue.getValue());
                buffer.append(",");
            } else {
                List<SubField> subFields = fieldValue.getSubFields();
                subFields.stream().map(SubField::getSubFieldValues).forEach(subFieldValues -> subFieldValues.forEach(subFieldValue -> {
                    buffer.append(subFieldValue.getValue());
                    buffer.append(",");
                }));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Stream.concat(
          list.stream().flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream()
                                    .map(FieldValue::getValue)), 
           list.stream()
               .flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream())
               .flatMap(fieldValue -> fieldValue.getSubFields().stream())
               .flatMap(subField -> subField.getSubFieldValues().stream())
               .map(SubFieldValue::getValue)
            )
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

**ComplexObject.java**

```
@Getter
public class ComplexObject
{
    private String globalCode;

    private List<Fields> fields;

}
```

**Fields.java**

```
@Getter
public class Fields
{
    private String localCode;
    private List<FieldValues> fieldValues;
}
```

**FieldValues.java**

```
@Getter
public class FieldValues {
    private String value;

    private List<SubFields> subFields;

}
```

SubFields.java

```
@Getter
public class SubFields
{
    private String localCode;

    private List<SubFieldValues> subFieldValues;

}
```

**SubFieldValues.Java**

```
@Getter
public class SubFieldValues{
    private String value;

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\n" +
                " \"globalCode\" : \"12\",\n" +
                "  \"fields\" : [\n" +
                "     {\n" +
                "           \"localCode\" : \"72879\",\n" +
                "           \"fieldValues\" : [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                      \"value\" : null,\n" +
                "                      \"subFields\" : [\n" +
                "                           {\n" +
                "                                 \"localCode\" : \"980\",\n" +
                "                                 \"subFieldValues\" : [\n" +
                "                                         {\n" +
                "                                          \"value\" :  \"lon\"\n" +
                "                                         }\n" +
                "                                  ]\n" +
                "                           },\n" +
                "                            {\n" +
                "                                 \"localCode\" : \"98\",\n" +
                "                                 \"subFieldValues\" : [\n" +
                "                                         {\n" +
                "                                          \"value\" :  \"KPO\"\n" +
                "                                         }\n" +
                "                                  ]\n" +
                "                           }\n" +
                "                              \n" +
                "\n" +
                "                      ]\n" +
                "                }       \n" +
                "           ]\n" +
                "     }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";
        ComplexObject complexObject = objectMapper.readValue(json, ComplexObject.class);


        List<Fields> fields = complexObject.getFields();
        Stream.concat(
                fields.stream().flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream()
                        .map(FieldValues::getValue)),
                fields.stream()
                        .flatMap(field -> field.getFieldValues().stream())
                        .flatMap(fieldValue -> fieldValue.getSubFields().stream())
                        .flatMap(subField -> subField.getSubFieldValues().stream())
                        .map(SubFieldValues::getValue)
        )
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .reduce((s, s2) -> s + "," + s2).ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
lon,KPO
```

Note:

- JSON is invalid, you missed few commas. I have fixed it also.